# Trying to deploy Rails App with Capistrano to Do Droplet

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, capistrano

I would like to deploy my app on my server and use capistrano. However, I come across the following error(s) again and again and don't know how to fix it. First the error was that he couldn't find Yarn or something was wrong with the Yui Compressor i guess, i think cant file or something like that. Then i installed Yarn on my terminal and the error changed to this one:

```html
Caused by:
SSHKit::Command::Failed: rake exit status: 1
rake stdout: DEPRECATION WARNING: Sprockets method register_engine is deprecated.
Please register a mime type using register_mime_type then
use register_compressor or register_transformer.
https://github.com/rails/sprockets/blob/master/guides/extending_sprockets.md#supporting-all-versions-of-sprockets-in-processors
(called from block in class:Railtie at /home/deploy/apps/Blogapp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/less-rails-2.8.0/lib/less/rails/railtie.rb:16)
DEPRECATION WARNING: You are using a deprecated processor interface Less::Rails::ImportProcessor.
Please update your processor interface:
https://github.com/rails/sprockets/blob/master/guides/extending_sprockets.md#supporting-all-versions-of-sprockets-in-processors
(called from block in class:Railtie at /home/deploy/apps/Blogapp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/less-rails-2.8.0/lib/less/rails/railtie.rb:21)
Yarn executable was not detected in the system.
Download Yarn at https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/install
/home/deploy/apps/Blogapp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/bin/rake: No such file or directory - java
rake aborted!
YUI::Compressor::RuntimeError: Command 'java -jar /home/deploy/apps/Blogapp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/yui-compressor-0.12.0/lib/yui/../yuicompressor-2.4.8.jar --type css --charset utf-8 /tmp/yui_compress20180918-14505-sgrpkh' returned non-zero exit status
/home/deploy/apps/Blogapp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/yui-compressor-0.12.0/lib/yui/compressor.rb:106:in block in compress'
/home/deploy/apps/Blogapp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/yui-compressor-0.12.0/lib/yui/compressor.rb:141:instreamify'
/home/deploy/apps/Blogapp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/yui-compressor-0.12.0/lib/yui/compressor.rb:86:in compress'
/home/deploy/apps/Blogapp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/yui_compressor.rb:49:incall'
/home/deploy/apps/Blogapp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/yui_compressor.rb:28:in call'
/home/deploy/apps/Blogapp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:75:incall_processor'
/home/deploy/apps/Blogapp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:57:in block in call_processors'
/home/deploy/apps/Blogapp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:56:inreverse_each'
/home/deploy/apps/Blogapp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:56:in call_processors'
/home/deploy/apps/Blogapp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:134:inload_from_unloaded'
/home/deploy/apps/Blogapp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:60:in block in load'
/home/deploy/apps/Blogapp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:317:infetch_asset_from_dependency_cache'
/home/deploy/apps/Blogapp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:44:in load'
/home/deploy/apps/Blogapp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:20:inblock in initialize'
/home/deploy/apps/Blogapp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:47:in load'
/home/deploy/apps/Blogapp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:66:infind_asset'
/home/deploy/apps/Blogapp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:73:in find_all_linked_assets'
/home/deploy/apps/Blogapp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:142:inblock in find'
/home/deploy/apps/Blogapp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:114:in block (2 levels) in logical_paths'
/home/deploy/apps/Blogapp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:228:inblock in stat_tree'
/home/deploy/apps/Blogapp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:212:in block in stat_directory'
/home/deploy/apps/Blogapp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:209:ineach'
/home/deploy/apps/Blogapp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:209:in stat_directory'
/home/deploy/apps/Blogapp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:227:instat_tree'
/home/deploy/apps/Blogapp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:105:in each'
/home/deploy/apps/Blogapp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:105:inblock in logical_paths'
/home/deploy/apps/Blogapp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:104:in each'
/home/deploy/apps/Blogapp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:104:inlogical_paths'
/home/deploy/apps/Blogapp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:140:in find'
/home/deploy/apps/Blogapp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:186:incompile'
/home/deploy/apps/Blogapp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-rails-3.2.1/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:68:in block (3 levels) in define'
/home/deploy/apps/Blogapp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/rake/sprocketstask.rb:147:inwith_logger'
/home/deploy/apps/Blogapp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-rails-3.2.1/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:67:in block (2 levels) in define'
/home/deploy/apps/Blogapp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/rake-12.3.1/exe/rake:27:in'
/home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/bundler-1.16.5/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:74:in load'
/home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/bundler-1.16.5/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:74:inkernel_load'
/home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/bundler-1.16.5/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:28:in run'
/home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/bundler-1.16.5/lib/bundler/cli.rb:424:inexec'
/home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/bundler-1.16.5/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in run'
/home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/bundler-1.16.5/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:ininvoke_command'
/home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/bundler-1.16.5/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor.rb:387:in dispatch'
/home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/bundler-1.16.5/lib/bundler/cli.rb:27:indispatch'
/home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/bundler-1.16.5/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/base.rb:466:in start'
/home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/bundler-1.16.5/lib/bundler/cli.rb:18:instart'
/home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/bundler-1.16.5/exe/bundle:30:in block in <top (required)>'
/home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/bundler-1.16.5/lib/bundler/friendly_errors.rb:124:inwith_friendly_errors'
/home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/bundler-1.16.5/exe/bundle:22:in <top (required)>'
/home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/bin/bundle:23:inload'
/home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/bin/bundle:23:in <main>'
/home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:24:ineval'
/home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:24:in `'
Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
rake stderr: Nothing written

Tasks: TOP => deploy:assets:precompile
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
The deploy has failed with an error: Exception while executing on host 104.248.180.170: rake exit status: 1
rake stdout: DEPRECATION WARNING: Sprockets method register_engine is deprecated.
Please register a mime type using register_mime_type then
use register_compressor or register_transformer.
https://github.com/rails/sprockets/blob/master/guides/extending_sprockets.md#supporting-all-versions-of-sprockets-in-processors
(called from block in class:Railtie at /home/deploy/apps/Blogapp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/less-rails-2.8.0/lib/less/rails/railtie.rb:16)
DEPRECATION WARNING: You are using a deprecated processor interface Less::Rails::ImportProcessor.
Please update your processor interface:
https://github.com/rails/sprockets/blob/master/guides/extending_sprockets.md#supporting-all-versions-of-sprockets-in-processors
(called from block in class:Railtie at /home/deploy/apps/Blogapp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/less-rails-2.8.0/lib/less/rails/railtie.rb:21)
Yarn executable was not detected in the system.
Download Yarn at https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/install
/home/deploy/apps/Blogapp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/bin/rake: No such file or directory - java
rake aborted!
YUI::Compressor::RuntimeError: Command 'java -jar /home/deploy/apps/Blogapp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/yui-compressor-0.12.0/lib/yui/../yuicompressor-2.4.8.jar --type css --charset utf-8 /tmp/yui_compress20180918-14505-sgrpkh' returned non-zero exit status
/home/deploy/apps/Blogapp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/yui-compressor-0.12.0/lib/yui/compressor.rb:106:in block in compress'
/home/deploy/apps/Blogapp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/yui-compressor-0.12.0/lib/yui/compressor.rb:141:instreamify'
/home/deploy/apps/Blogapp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/yui-compressor-0.12.0/lib/yui/compressor.rb:86:in compress'
/home/deploy/apps/Blogapp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/yui_compressor.rb:49:incall'
/home/deploy/apps/Blogapp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/yui_compressor.rb:28:in call'
/home/deploy/apps/Blogapp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:75:incall_processor'
/home/deploy/apps/Blogapp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:57:in block in call_processors'
/home/deploy/apps/Blogapp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:56:inreverse_each'
/home/deploy/apps/Blogapp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:56:in call_processors'
/home/deploy/apps/Blogapp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:134:inload_from_unloaded'
/home/deploy/apps/Blogapp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:60:in block in load'
/home/deploy/apps/Blogapp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:317:infetch_asset_from_dependency_cache'
/home/deploy/apps/Blogapp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:44:in load'
/home/deploy/apps/Blogapp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:20:inblock in initialize'
/home/deploy/apps/Blogapp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:47:in load'
/home/deploy/apps/Blogapp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:66:infind_asset'
/home/deploy/apps/Blogapp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:73:in find_all_linked_assets'
/home/deploy/apps/Blogapp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:142:inblock in find'
/home/deploy/apps/Blogapp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:114:in block (2 levels) in logical_paths'
/home/deploy/apps/Blogapp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:228:inblock in stat_tree'
/home/deploy/apps/Blogapp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:212:in block in stat_directory'
/home/deploy/apps/Blogapp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:209:ineach'
/home/deploy/apps/Blogapp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:209:in stat_directory'
/home/deploy/apps/Blogapp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:227:instat_tree'
/home/deploy/apps/Blogapp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:105:in each'
/home/deploy/apps/Blogapp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:105:inblock in logical_paths'
/home/deploy/apps/Blogapp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:104:in each'
/home/deploy/apps/Blogapp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:104:inlogical_paths'
/home/deploy/apps/Blogapp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:140:in find'
/home/deploy/apps/Blogapp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:186:incompile'
/home/deploy/apps/Blogapp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-rails-3.2.1/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:68:in block (3 levels) in define'
/home/deploy/apps/Blogapp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/rake/sprocketstask.rb:147:inwith_logger'
/home/deploy/apps/Blogapp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-rails-3.2.1/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:67:in block (2 levels) in define'
/home/deploy/apps/Blogapp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/rake-12.3.1/exe/rake:27:in'
/home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/bundler-1.16.5/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:74:in load'
/home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/bundler-1.16.5/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:74:inkernel_load'
/home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/bundler-1.16.5/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:28:in run'
/home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/bundler-1.16.5/lib/bundler/cli.rb:424:inexec'
/home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/bundler-1.16.5/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in run'
/home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/bundler-1.16.5/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:ininvoke_command'
/home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/bundler-1.16.5/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor.rb:387:in dispatch'
/home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/bundler-1.16.5/lib/bundler/cli.rb:27:indispatch'
/home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/bundler-1.16.5/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/base.rb:466:in start'
/home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/bundler-1.16.5/lib/bundler/cli.rb:18:instart'
/home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/bundler-1.16.5/exe/bundle:30:in block in <top (required)>'
/home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/bundler-1.16.5/lib/bundler/friendly_errors.rb:124:inwith_friendly_errors'
/home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/bundler-1.16.5/exe/bundle:22:in <top (required)>'
/home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/bin/bundle:23:inload'
/home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/bin/bundle:23:in <main>'
/home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:24:ineval'
/home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:24:in `'
Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
rake stderr: Nothing written

** DEPLOY FAILED
```

My Capfile:

```html
# Load DSL and set up stages
require "capistrano/setup"

# Include default deployment tasks
require "capistrano/deploy"

# Load the SCM plugin appropriate to your project:
#
# require "capistrano/scm/hg"
# install_plugin Capistrano::SCM::Hg
# or
# require "capistrano/scm/svn"
# install_plugin Capistrano::SCM::Svn
# or
require "capistrano/scm/git"
install_plugin Capistrano::SCM::Git

# Include tasks from other gems included in your Gemfile
#
# For documentation on these, see for example:
#
 # https://github.com/capistrano/rvm
#   https://github.com/capistrano/rbenv
#   https://github.com/capistrano/chruby
#   https://github.com/capistrano/bundler
#   https://github.com/capistrano/rails
#   https://github.com/capistrano/passenger
#

require "capistrano/bundler"
require "capistrano/rvm"
require "capistrano/rails/assets"
 require "capistrano/rails/migrations"
 require "capistrano/passenger"
require "capistrano/puma"

# Load custom tasks from `lib/capistrano/tasks` if you have any defined
Dir.glob("lib/capistrano/tasks/*.rake").each { |r| import r }
```

My Deploy.rb

```html
# Change these
server 'xxx.xxx.xxx', port: 22, roles: [:web, :app, :db], primary: true

set :repo_url,        'git@github.com:WebSepp/Blogapp.git'
set :application,     'Blogapp'
set :user,            'deploy'
set :puma_threads,    [4, 16]
set :puma_workers,    0

# Don't change these unless you know what you're doing
set :pty,             true
set :use_sudo,        false
set :stage,           :production
set :deploy_via,      :remote_cache
set :deploy_to,       "/home/#{fetch(:user)}/apps/#{fetch(:application)}"
set :puma_bind,       "unix://#{shared_path}/tmp/sockets/#{fetch(:application)}-puma.sock"
set :puma_state,      "#{shared_path}/tmp/pids/puma.state"
set :puma_pid,        "#{shared_path}/tmp/pids/puma.pid"
set :puma_access_log, "#{release_path}/log/puma.error.log"
set :puma_error_log,  "#{release_path}/log/puma.access.log"
set :ssh_options,     { forward_agent: true, user: fetch(:user), keys: %w(~/.ssh/usa) }
set :linked_files, %w{config/master.key}
set :puma_preload_app, true
set :puma_worker_timeout, nil
set :puma_init_active_record, true  # Change to false when not using ActiveRecord

## Defaults:
# set :scm,           :git
# set :branch,        :master
# set :format,        :pretty
# set :log_level,     :debug
# set :keep_releases, 5

## Linked Files & Directories (Default None):
# set :linked_files, %w{config/database.yml}
# set :linked_dirs,  %w{bin log tmp/pids tmp/cache tmp/sockets vendor/bundle public/system}

namespace :puma do
  desc 'Create Directories for Puma Pids and Socket'
  task :make_dirs do
    on roles(:app) do
      execute "mkdir #{shared_path}/tmp/sockets -p"
      execute "mkdir #{shared_path}/tmp/pids -p"
    end
  end

  before :start, :make_dirs
end

namespace :deploy do
  desc "Make sure local git is in sync with remote."
  task :check_revision do
    on roles(:app) do
      unless `git rev-parse HEAD` == `git rev-parse origin/master`
        puts "WARNING: HEAD is not the same as origin/master"
        puts "Run `git push` to sync changes."
        exit
      end
    end
  end

  desc 'Initial Deploy'
  task :initial do
    on roles(:app) do
      before 'deploy:restart', 'puma:start'
      invoke 'deploy'
    end
  end

  desc 'Restart application'
  task :restart do
    on roles(:app), in: :sequence, wait: 5 do
      invoke 'puma:restart'
    end
  end

  before :starting,     :check_revision
  after  :finishing,    :compile_assets
  after  :finishing,    :cleanup
  after  :finishing,    :restart
end

# ps aux | grep puma    # Get puma pid
# kill -s SIGUSR2 pid   # Restart puma
# kill -s SIGTERM pid   # Stop puma
```

My Gemfile:

```html
source 'https://rubygems.org'
git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }

ruby '2.5.1'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '~> 5.2.0'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
gem 'sqlite3'
# Use Puma as the app server
group :development do

    gem "capistrano", "~> 3.7"
    gem "capistrano-rails", "~> 1.2"
    gem "capistrano-passenger", "~> 0.2.0"
    gem "capistrano-yarn"
    gem "capistrano-puma"
    gem "capistrano-rvm"
    #Add this if you"re using rbenv

end

gem 'puma'
gem 'sprockets-rails', :require => 'sprockets/railtie'

# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'mini_racer', platforms: :ruby

# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'
# Turbolinks makes navigating your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'
# Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
# gem 'redis', '~> 4.0'
# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'
#



gem 'jquery-rails', '~> 4.3', '>= 4.3.3'


#gem less style
gem 'therubyracer'

gem 'less-rails' #Sprockets (what Rails 3.1 uses for its asset pipeline) supports LESS
#Use twitter bootstrap
gem 'twitter-bootstrap-rails'

gem 'friendly_id', '~> 5.2.0'

gem 'will_paginate', '~> 3.1.0'

gem 'trix-rails', require: 'trix'

gem 'shrine'

gem 'devise'

gem 'timepiece'

gem 'social-share-button'







# Use ActiveStorage variant
# gem 'mini_magick', '~> 4.8'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

# Reduces boot times through caching; required in config/boot.rb
gem 'bootsnap', '>= 1.1.0', require: false

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
end

group :development do
  # Access an interactive console on exception pages or by calling 'console' anywhere in the code.
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
  gem 'listen', '>= 3.0.5', '< 3.2'
  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
end

group :test do
  # Adds support for Capybara system testing and selenium driver
  gem 'capybara', '>= 2.15', '< 4.0'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
  # Easy installation and use of chromedriver to run system tests with Chrome
  gem 'chromedriver-helper'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

Would really appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

> Yarn executable was not detected in the system.
>   Download Yarn at https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/install

Did you install Yarn on your server?

Comment: Did it work out for you? I'm stuck on the same issue with `Ruby 2.5.1`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a gem you've included in your application has a dependency on java. From the [`ruby-yui-compressor`](https://github.com/sstephenson/ruby-yui-compressor/) homepage:

> Because YUI Compressor's .jar file is included in the box, Java >= 1.4 is its only dependency.

Essentially you need to install java on your server or, if it is already installed, make it available to your `deploy` user.